# Did the Space Stone have to be wrapped back into the Tesseract to be returned?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Did Captain America have to wrap the Space Stone back up in the Tesseract when he took it back so that it could later be crushed by Thanos?

Other Infinity Stones exist as Stones so returning them is just a matter of being in the right place. The Space Stone is meant to be in the cube for some time. So, what happened when Captain America went back?

Comment: This would also apply to the Mind and Reality Stones, if I'm remembering rightly, for the Scepter and Aether respectively.

Comment: Yes, it would, but I couldn't find a reference to how the Scepter was constructed. I was wondering if the Captain had to make a side trip to Asgard to have the Tesseract restored or if reality would pull it back into shape or some other event happened to bring the stones back to where they were.

Comment: If I understood the movie correctly, it wasn't necessary for everything about the timeline to remain the same as the original one; it was only necessary to return the Infinity Stones to the timeline(s) they were taken from.

Comment: Presumably, Cap could have just left the Space Stone at the SHIELD facility in New Jersey and leave the question of who broke the Tesseract as a mystery they would never solve.

Comment: Who broke the people's Tesseract? 'Twas him ->

Comment: @NathanK. That is worth adding as an answer :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Steve has the Time Stone. With Strange's help or the help of The Sorcerer Supreme to show him how to use it (or simply use it themselves), reverting the various stones to their original forms would be trivially simple.

Similarly, with access to the Space Stone, traveling to Morag and Vormir would just be a snap.

---

That being said, The Sorcerer Supreme tells Banner that the flow will be uninterrupted ***if the stone is present in that universe***. She doesn't talk about what it's enclosed in although I think we can assume that he put each stone back *as it was before.*

Comment: Could Cap use the stones without suffering side effects though? If Thanos was affected after using them?...

Comment: @Odin1806 - He knows at least one person in the earlier timeline (the Sorceror Supreme) who would be willing and perfectly capable of using the Time Stone without any ill effects.

Comment: Good point. I should have thought of that...

Comment: See also: the apple in Doctor Strange

Comment: @user1 The apple was reversed by only a few minutes. If Dr Strange could reverse the stone back to its previous form then why didn't he just do that to everyone and everything? Including Thanos. "Hello Evil Guy, prepare for.. Babality!"

Comment: @Underverse - Thanos can (presumably) use the other stones to block the effects of the Time Stone

Comment: @Underverse perhaps you should pose that question to the forum as he certainly had the ability to reverse the effects of time on a massive scale. He put an entire dimension in a time loop.